# Mocking API for delete operation in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, api

I want to create a mocking api with delete operation in azure api management. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Policy:

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <mock-response status-code="200" content-type="application/json" />
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
    <mock-response status-code="200" content-type="application/json" />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
    <mock-response status-code="200" content-type="application/json" />
</on-error>
```

OpenApi:

```
delete:
  summary: DELETE (200)
  description: '/dev/null for delete operations (write), returns 200 - OK'
  operationId: delete
  responses:
    '200':
      description: 'OK'
```